# makefile, working fine but running commands even with no changes

Tags: c, makefile

I have the following make file. The problem is that even if there are no changes in  the two .cpp files, it still run all the commands on prompt. Everything else is working fine.

```
all: hello1

hello1: make func 

        gcc hellomake.o hellofunc.o -o hello -I.

make: hellomake.c 

        gcc -c hellomake.c

func: hellofunc.c

        gcc -c hellofunc.c

clean:

        rm -rf *o hello

run:

        ./hello
```

Comment: You should replace *make*, *func* with *hellomake.o*, *hellofunc.o* in your Makefile.

Comment: To expand on the @NickZavaritsky's comment (which he should make into an Answer), `make` and `func` are targets, but those rules don't actually build files called "make" and "func", so Make always thinks those files are missing and must be rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample Makefile that you can modifiy (especially CFLAGS section), and in won't relink

```
NAME    = xxx
SRCS    = xxx.c
OBJS    = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

CC      = gcc
RM      = rm -rf

CFLAGS  +=  -W -Wall -Wextra
CFLAGS  += -O2
CFLAGS  += -ansi -pedantic
CFLAGS  += -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE

all:    $(NAME)

$(NAME):        $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(NAME)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS)

fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(NAME)

re:     fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

.PHONY allow to differentiate eventual file names and rule names

Answer (score -1):

You need to replace the .c to .o in the targets as described below

```
make: hellomake.o 

        gcc -c hellomake.c

func: hellofunc.o

        gcc -c hellofunc.c
```